# Using a huffman tree to decode binary text

Tags: c++, tree, huffman-code, inorder, postorder

The snippet below is not returning the correct text. The code takes in a pointer to the root node of a Huffman code tree and a binary text, which it then converts. However, every time it returns a single letter repeated.

```
string decode(Node *root, string code) {
    string d = ""; char c; Node *node = root;
    for (int i = 0; i < code.size(); i++) {
        node = (code[i] == '0') ? node->left_child : node->right_child;
        if ((c = node->value) < 128) {
            d += c;
            node = root;
        }
    }
    return d;
}
```

The code for the Node object:

```
class Node {
public:
  Node(int i, Node *l = nullptr, Node *r = nullptr) {
      value = i;
      left_child = l;
      right_child = r;
  }
  int value;
  Node *left_child;
  Node *right_child;
};
```

The code for building the tree:

```
Node* buildTree(vector<int> in, vector<int> post, int in_left, int in_right, int *post_index) {
    Node *node = new Node(post[*post_index]);
    (*post_index)--;

    if (in_left == in_right) {
        return node;
    }

    int in_index;
    for (int i = in_left; i <= in_right; i++) {
        if (in[i] == node->value) {
            in_index = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    node->right_child = buildTree(in, post, in_index + 1, in_right, post_index);
    node->left_child = buildTree(in, post, in_left, in_index - 1, post_index);

    return node;
}
```

Example tree:

```
        130
       /   \
     129    65
    /   \
  66     128
        /   \
      76     77
```

Example I/O:
Input: `101010010111`
Output: `A�A�A��A�AAA`

The diamond characters are the numbers greater than 128.

Comment: Any debugger usage on your part?

Comment: You'd be surprised to learn that "`code[i] == 0`" does ***not***, I repeat, does not check if the ith character in the `code` std::string is the character '0' a.k.a. ASCII code 48.

Comment: I like your `Node` class. You'd be surprised how many people don't bother to ensure the link pointers are nulled.

Comment: @Sam Varshavchik, sorry it should be '0'. It was caught that before I posted, but didn't edit it out.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, debugger outputs "[Inferior 1 (process 20521) exited normally]"

Comment: @TylerWest -- No, you did not use the debugger in the way that it is meant to be used.  The debugger allows you to run your program step-by-step, one function / line at a time, allowing you to watch variables, observe the flow, set breakpoints, etc.  What you did is simply run your program at full-speed with no debugging being done.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie, in (gdb) I typed "r arg1 arg2 arg3" and that was the final output. Is that wrong?

Comment: So I guess you never used a debugger before.  Didn't you step through the program one line at a time, or at least investigate how to do that?  You really need to learn how to use a debugger -- it is a tool that every programmer has to learn to use, no exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

You are putting the value in a `char`, which for most C++ compilers is signed. But not all -- whether char is signed or unsigned is implementation defined. A signed char is in the range –128 to 127, so it is *always* less than 128. (Your compiler should have warned you about that.)

You need to use `int c;` instead of `char c;` in `decode()`, and do `d += (char)c;`. Then your first code snippet will correctly return `ALABAMA`.

By the way, there needs to be an error check in `decode()`, verifying that you exit the loop with `node` equal to `root`. Otherwise, there were some bits provided that ended in the middle of a code, and so were not decoded to a symbol.

Comment: The tree is right. Both the inorder and postorder traversals match if you run through them again. Also, I added the error check.